# Regarding profile url shorten

Tags: url

I am wondering to know about this is it possible or not. If yes then please help me.

I want to change this URL:
http://domain.com/profile/admin
to
http://domain.com/admin

Where admin is username of profile user.
Why I am thinking it is impossible like the URL is already rewritten in .htaccess or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You provide a little to less context to give a definitive answer but it must certainly be possible. It all depends on how you have setup your code and webserver now and in what degree you are allowed to modify any of them.

Comment: hi @baszz it is on socialengine4 PHP CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet in your .htaccess file -

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /admin

  RewriteRule ^/profile (.*) $1 [R=301,L]

 </IfModule>
```

This snippet won't work if the URL- http://domain.com/profile/admin is auto-generated in between the application.